# cannot config LDAP in filenet p8 5.2

Tags: active-directory, ldap, filenet-p8, content-platform-engine

i tried to fulfill this form below many times and click "test LDAP connection". it's alway return success. but when i click "run task", it's alway return

> Running the task failed with the following message: The LDAP authentication configuration failed.
>
> WASX7209I: Connected to process "server1" on node p8 using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: UnManagedProcess
>       test standalone LDAP repository
>
> WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\FileNet\ContentEngine\tools\configure\tmp/configureldap.tcl"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.CommandException:
>
> SECJ7340E: Exception raised trying to connect to LDAP server: AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db0

Form: 
[image]

I used an Window Server 2008r2 with a domain controller. 
please help me fulfill this form or give me some examples how I can make it work!

Comment: So how did you format your bind user and base distuguished name then? It must be something with the credentials because of the 'dat 52e' flag in the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the  'data 52e' should mean that the credential data is invalid, either invalid user(or it cant find the user) or password

values should be fully qualified like this:

```
CN=svcLDAP,OU=FileNet,DC=myfilenetdomain,DC=local
```

directory bind user(primary user to query the LDAP with):

```
CN=[you ladp user],OU=[your user group, filenet in my case]FileNet,DC=[your domain],DC=local
```

base distinguished name is the primary group where all your FN users will be in:

```
OU=[your user group, filenet in my case]FileNet,DC=[your domain],DC=local
```

Ofcourse these settings are highly dependant on your directory configuration and can vary from my awnser.

Be sure to use the Test LDAP Connection button. If that says its fine, it should be fine to run the task.

Another hint: use the tool adsi edit(its a standard MS tool for active direcotry) it will show you very easily all the fully qualified data for ldap
https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc773354%28v=ws.10%29.aspx